# Laravel 5.1 - Setting a global variable for all the users and models

Tags: php, global-variables, laravel-5.1

I am developing a Laravel 5.1 app for managing projects. The admin set the project to work with, and technicians will work over that project. It is possible that one day a technician or more enter the platform and have no global project, in that case some modules won't be accesible.

I was thinking on registering some kind of global variable and to do a middleware which checks that var and allow or deny access to the controller if it is not set.

Here comes the doubt, how I set this variable? I mean, is the best option to set a ServiceProvider which search DB everytime middleware requests the data? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Its all in your hands how to make it.. There is no right way, only yours..

Comment: Surely if it's truly global, then an environment setting would be better than a database hit every request

Comment: Did you mean .env file settings? Could be set this settings on execution time by the app?

Comment: Yes I meant .env file settings, if it's truly a global default value as you say, then there's no need for it to be set on execution time by the app; but it could be if you really wanted that..... alternative would be a cached value rather than in the database

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers

Comment: You can improve your solution using a cache provider. By this way you avoid query the db in each request. When update the cache value? Only when a new project is available for a technician, then the middleware class will check this cache's var instead db.

Comment: Great solution, didn't figured out of this possibility. I will implement that, thanks!